# I am facing an value error while downloading / scrape images from scrapy spider i am using Image pipelines

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy, pipeline

I got an value error:

```
raise ValueError('Missing scheme in request url: %s' % self._url)

ValueError: Missing scheme in request url: h
```

My items.py code is:

```
class Brand(scrapy.Item):
    name = scrapy.Field()
    url = scrapy.Field()
    brand_image = scrapy.Field()
    image_urls = scrapy.Field()
    images = scrapy.Field()
```

My setting.py is:

```
BOT_NAME = 'scraper'    
SPIDER_MODULES = ['scraper.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'scraper.spiders'
ITEM_PIPELINES = {'scrapy.contrib.pipeline.images.ImagesPipeline': 1}
IMAGES_STORE = 'images'
```

My spider code:

```
import scrapy
import json
from scraper.items import Brand


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "brandDetails"
    allowed_domains = ["ozhat-turkiye.com"]
    with open('brands.json') as data_file:
        data_item = json.load(data_file)
        start_urls = list()
    for item in data_item:
        start_urls.append(item["url"])

    def parse(self, response):
        item = Brand()
        name = response.css("div.th::text").extract_first()
        name = name.replace('Products of ', '')
        item['name'] = name
        item['url'] = response.url
        urls = response.css("div.productimage img::attr(src)").extract_first()
        urls = response.urljoin(urls)
        item['image_urls'] = urls
        yield item
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Missing scheme in request url
```

always means that your URL is not valid, its missing `http://` and `https://`

So prepend `https://` or `http://` before the image url you have

```
`https://` + response.css("div.productimage img::attr(src)").extract_first()
```